# Why does datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime.now() equal to datetime.timedelta(-1, 86399, 999974)?

Tags: python, datetime

Consider the following snippet:

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime.now())
```

On my Python 2.7.8 under x86_64 Linux, I am getting `-1 day, 23:59:59.999940`. Why could be that?

Comment: I can confirm the same behavior under python 2.6.6. in Win7. But not the same for Python 3.4 Win7. So I guess they had a wee bit of a bug happen?

Comment: @ljetibo: no, the behaviour is by design.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah, I saw your answer just as I posted my comment. It's still funny that it doesn't do the same in Py3 though where it pops out `0:00:00`

Comment: @ljetibo: then you called `datetime.datetime.now()` with no delay between the calls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the `datetime.timedelta` documenation:

> Note that normalization of negative values may be surprising at first. For example,
>
> ```
> >>> from datetime import timedelta
> >>> d = timedelta(microseconds=-1)
> >>> (d.days, d.seconds, d.microseconds) (-1, 86399, 999999)
> ```

You have a negative timedelta, and normalisation always uses *positive numbers* for seconds and microseconds.

To store a negative delta then where only the *`.days`* attribute can store negative values, you end up with a `-1` day plus a positive amount of seconds and microseconds:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> td = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime.now()
>>> print(td)
-1 day, 23:59:59.999988
>>> td
datetime.timedelta(-1, 86399, 999988)
>>> td.days
-1
>>> td.seconds
86399
>>> td.microseconds
999988
>>> (24 * 60 * 60)  # 1 day in seconds
86400
>>> (24 * 60 * 60) - td.seconds
1
>>> 1000000 - td.microseconds
12
```

So the `timedelta` really represents `-12` microseconds, but expressed relative to -1 day that becomes +86399 seconds and +999988 microseconds.

Comment: Thanks! Shouldn't this be an exception though then?

Comment: What do you mean? Why would this need to be an exception?

Comment: Because the results don't make sense.

Comment: @d33tah: I explained the results. For efficiency when processing and comparison tests the values are normalised where seconds and microseconds can only be using *positive integers*. You cannot store `-12 seconds` in a `timedelta`, instead it stores `-1 day plus 86388 seconds`. The end result is the same. Compare this to travelling to another country by flying into the neighbouring country then taking the train to the destination, where the destination lies between you and that neighbouring country.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but on the other hand I think that the interface is wrong. It does not signal that invalid input was given and instead gives just weird data.

Comment: @d33tah: there was no invalid input! Where did you get the idea there was invalid input? You subtracted two datetime objects, that's perfectly valid. Because the second one is later in time than the first, you get a negative timedelta.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it now. -1 day plus 23:59:59.999940 = some miliseconds. Weird anyway, but makes a bit more sense.

Comment: @d33tah: yes, some *negative* milliseconds. :-)

Comment: @d33tah: call `abs(td)` to see the absolute value e.g., `print "%s%s" % ("-" if td < ZERO else "", abs(td))` where `ZERO = datetime.timedelta(0)`.